# I have a numpy and or pandas array that repeats, how do i find out where and when it does?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, append

Ok, this is pandas but i don't care if there is a pandas or numpy solution, i'm just looking for a solution to see where the pattern repeats: Here is what is have:

```
Out[713]: 
     sf  sx  sz  ss
0    12  15   5   6
1    15   1  13   3
2    13  10   6   1
3     9  14   8  15
4     2   2   6   6
5     8   8   2   2
6    15   8   2   5
7     4   6   9  11
8    14  13  10   9
9     2  12   5  11
10    1   6  15   8
11    3   4   9  14
12   12  12  14  14
13   15  15   5   5
14   13  10  10  13
15    9  11  13  15
16    2   1  10   9
17    8   6   3  13
18   15   8  14   9
19    4   3  13  10
20   14  14   2   2
21    2   2   5   5
22    1   6   1   6
23    3   1  13  15
24   12  15   0   3
25   15   1   9   7
26   13  10   2   5
27    9  14  14   9
28    2   2   2   2
29    8   8   2   2
30   15   8  10  13
31    4   6  15  13
32   14  13   5   6
33    2  12   5  11
34    1   6  13  10
35    3   4   5   2
36   12  12  13  13
37   15  15   6   6
38   13  10   8  15
39    9  11   6   4
40    2   1   2   1
41    8   6   2  12
42   15   8   9  14
43    4   3  10  13
44   14  14   5   5
45    2   2  15  15
46    1   6   9  14
47    3   1  14  12
48   12  15   5   6
49   15   1  10   4
50   13  10  13  10


use pd.read_clipboard()
if you want to copy paste
```

you can see that sf repeats every slice of 12, and sx repeats every slice of 24, and sz repeats at every slice of 35. How do i figure out where these slices repeats without manually checking them, and also slice ss repeats, but i can't seem to figure out how. What strategies can i use to figure out where ss repeats.

Thanks in advance, i couldn't find an answer so wanted to as anyone with knowledge of this situation.

ss is actually just: ss = sf ^ sx ^ sz
if that helps

Thanks

Comment: I removed the second question to remove the multiple questions so it wont need more focus. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compute an autocorrelation with [`autocorr`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.autocorr.html) and a custom function:

```
import numpy as np

def get_lag(s):
    return next((lag for lag in range(1, len(s))
                if np.isclose(s.autocorr(lag=lag), 1)), 0)

df.apply(get_lag)
```

*NB. I used a correlation of almost 1 as value and stop on the first match, you can also adapt the logic to use a threshold if you're fine with an approximate match.*

Output:

```
sf    12
sx    24
sz    35
ss     0
dtype: int64
```